# Are dependent variables random?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, regression, conditional-expectation, linear-regression

A linear regression model can be described as:
$$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon $$
where $\epsilon$ is the zero mean normal error. My question is: Is $X$ random variable?
If no, then how can we define
$$ \mathbb{E}[y\mid X]$$
as $X$ is a deterministic. If yes, then what do we mean by this (found in the wikipedia page) "we want to find how changing the value of $X$, changes $typical/expected$ value of $y$?" Are we talking about an instance of random X or expected value of X?
link for wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a sense, whenever you find a conditional probability or a conditional expected value or a conditional variance, you are temporarily treating the event of the random variable on which you condition as if it were not random. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and you seek $\operatorname{E}(X^2 Y \mid X).$ That conditional expected value is $X^2\operatorname{E}(Y \mid X).$ The factor $X^2$ is pulled out of the expectation operator just as if it had been (for example) the number $3.$

Very statistical data originate in a way that results in pairs $(X_i,Y_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ in which both components are random, and then linear regression is used. The probabilistic models on which are based such tests as whether the correlation is significant often assume $X$ is not random and $Y$ is random. The justification for that is that one is  interested in the conditional expected value and conditional variance of $Y$ given $X$.

Sometimes, however, the $X$ values can be chosen by the experimenter, and the $Y$ values are then provided by nature (or things outside the experimenter's control). The same statistical methods may then be applied, and again one is interested in the distribution of $Y$ given $X$. In such a case $X$ is not random, but in either case there is a justification for treating it as not random.

Comment: Great explanation. I didn't get the second part. Shouldn't it be single $X$ not $X_i$? Meaning, we are trying to estimate how expectation of $Y$ changes as $X$ takes different instances $X = x$?

Comment: @IsamAbdullah : Yes. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

No, $X$ is a not a random variable in normal linear regression analysis.

The setup is as follows. We are given a set of paired data,
$$\{ (x_1, y_1), \dots,  (x_n , y_n)\}.$$

We view the $x_i$'s as constants. Then, for each $i$, we view $Y_i$ as a normally distributed random variable, with mean $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

The $Y_i$'s are assumed to be independent, and the values of $\beta_0, \beta_1$ and $\sigma^2$ are the same for each $i$. Thus, $$\mathbb E[Y_i] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i.$$
(So yes, I agree that writing "$\mathbb E[Y_i \mid x_i]$" instead of "$\mathbb E[Y_i]$" can be a bit misleading! People write "$\mathbb E[Y_i \mid x_i ] $" to indicate that "there is an expression for $\mathbb E[Y_i]$ given solely in terms of the value of $x_i$", but this should NOT be read as saying that $Y_i$ and $x_i$ are both random variables with a joint probability distribution and $\mathbb E[Y_i \mid x_i]$ is a conditional probability!)

Comment: I agree, but I think you should mention, that the whole set up can be extended to random $X$ (where $X$ has "nice properties"), and by replacing $\Bbb E[ . ]$ by $\Bbb E[. \mid X]$ we basically get the same results as in the non-random case

Comment: @Cettt I didn't know that! I learned this stuff from a basic book by Freund, where none of this was mentioned. If you have time, would you mind writing an answer explaining this? Because I've also been puzzled about this in the past!